# How To Display Admob Interstitial Every Time A Button Is Pressed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, interstitial

I'm a BEGINNER when it comes to Android Development. This is my first application. I would like to know how to display a Admob interstitial ad every time a button is pressed. I have managed to display a interstitial ad, but only on the first time the button is pressed. However, I am getting an error when trying to load the ad. Here is my code:

```
package com.mycash.borgjake.mycash;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import static com.mycash.borgjake.mycash.R.styleable.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private InterstitialAd mInterstitial;


Button btnClick;
Button btnWithdraw;

TextView txtBalance;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    txtBalance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String countValue = txtBalance.getText().toString();
            int dblCountValue = Integer.parseInt(countValue);

            if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitial.show();
            }

            mInterstitial.loadAd(request); //<---ERROR

            dblCountValue++;
            txtBalance.setText(String.valueOf(dblCountValue));



        }
    });

    mInterstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-2245289628812463/9905502438");
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
    mInterstitial.loadAd(request);

}

public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.button2) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Withdraw.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance. :)

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to call this function `mInterstitial.loadAd(request);` every time

or if you want to call it call it like that

```
mInterstitial.loadAd(request);
  if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitial.show();
  }
```

or remove this  `mInterstitial.loadAd(request);` from every time you click button .

Comment: the error i am getting is, " Cannot resolve symbol "Request" ".

Comment: this is the code what you are missing for showing ad 

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

Answer (score 0):

**Just Create a function and call it anywhere when you need it :**

```
public static void getAd(Context c) {

        //================Ad-section
        // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(c);
        // Insert the Ad Unit ID
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-YOUR/ID");

        // Request for Ads
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();

                // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
                interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

                interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        // Call displayInterstitial() function
                        displayInterstitial();
                    }
                });
            }
            public static void displayInterstitial() {
                // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
                if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                    interstitial.show();
                }
      //=======================
    }
```

**To Run in Emulator OR Test Device Use Instead :**

```
public static void getAd(Context c) {

            //================Ad-section
        // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(c);
        // Insert the Ad Unit ID
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-YOUR/ID");

        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
    mInterstitial.loadAd(request);
}
```

**Call to the function :**

```
getAd(getApplicationContext());
```